# Why do I need to start services using sudo when logged in as root in an LXC container?

Tags: service, root, lxc

I've got an unprivileged LXC container which I've set up following the steps outlined on [Stèphane Graber's website](https://www.stgraber.org/2014/01/17/lxc-1-0-unprivileged-containers/).

Things work pretty well, but I'm having trouble starting php-fpm even though I am logged in as `root`. If I do `sudo service php5-fpm start`, it works. However, If I just do `service php5-fpm start`, I get the below error

```
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/2028: Connection refused
```

Should I really have to start services using `sudo` when logged in as root?

**Update #1**

This is not an issue if i SSH into the container. It is apparently only an issue if I log in to the container using lxc-attach

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that it is necessary to prefix commands with the full path. 
Verify your $PATH variable after connecting, and the location of the command.